# change api fetch into axios call

Tags: reactjs

i am trying to change the api fetch into axios get method i dont know how to do that

```
 const fetchApi = () => {
    const request = getAllActivityData();

    request
      .api({
        params: {
          customer,
        },
      })
```

i want to call api like this using axios

i have added full code in codesandbox  it will be helpfull if u can edit the codesand box and make it working

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `token  
      },
    };

    axios.get("customer/get-all-activity-data/?customer=22", config)
.then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
     
    });
```

code sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-jasper-2jmri?file=/src/App.js:3137-3298

what i have tryed  the data is not showning but there are no error .
i am getting  data  in postman

https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-montalcini-j7nv7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: cannot see your getAllActivityData function?

Comment: export const getAllActivityData = (config) => {
    return SheBirthService.get('/customer/get-all-activity-data/', config)
}  @narliecholler

Comment: in the sandbox it doesn't exist? Bit confused of what you're trying here because you show an axios call in your useEffect? You could just move all your functionality into its .then promise?

Comment: yes i want to move my axios in to useeffect  that is what i want

Comment: @narliecholler can u pls help me with the sand box

Comment: @narliecholler  what iam trying to achive is something like this  but in this there is no error but data is not showing in post man data is coming

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-montalcini-j7nv7?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this, using async await...

```
const axiosCallFn = async () => {
  let url = '...'
  let config = {
    headers: {
      token: '...'
    }
  }

  try {
    let resp = await axios.get(url, config)
    return resp.data  
  } catch(e) {
    throw e
  }
}

// import the function into your component and use it like so
axiosCallFn()
  .then((data) => {
    // your functionality here.
  })
  .catch(() => {
    // your error functionality here.
  })
```

and then you can call your axiosCallFn in your useEffect.

Comment: ya something like this could u pls debug the codesandbox  i am not sure where i should paste this

Comment: you need to destruct data from Response, as it is one deeper.

Comment: have a look now, add that function in and call it within useEffect

Comment: can u edit the codesandbox pls  @narliecholler

Comment: the actual data for predefined and custom was present in the response.data.You can refer the link https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-napier-z0lod?file=/src/App.js

You had response.predefined in line 27

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-field-kdcj5?file=/src/App.js

Comment: this should work ^ let me know